# Python "ImportError: No module named...", but the module exists

Tags: python, path, importerror

My file directory tree looks like this:

```
my_repo
├── experiments
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── baz.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Inside `baz.py`, I try

```
from experiments.foo import FooExperiment
```

but I get

```
*** ImportError: No module named experiments.foo
```

When I open python from the terminal (Mac OSX 10.9) and run

```
from experiments.foo import FooExperiment
```

the class is imported properly. What is going on? Please help.

In both situations the `sys.path` is exactly the same, except when I'm in `baz.py` the current path (to `baz.py`) is included. And yes `/path/to/my_repo` is in my `sys.path` as well.

**EDIT**: my issue was with conflicting egg files, so reinstalling did the trick (below). Accepting @Austin Marshall's answer though because it's a viable solution to the general case of this problem.

```
pip uninstall my_repo
python setup.py develop --user
```

Comment: Can you include the print of `sys.path` when you are getting error? Can some other `experminets` package or module be in the `sys.path` that is shadowing the `experiments` package you created inside `my_repo` ?

Comment: how do you 'run' `baz.py` ? I see it is in the tests dir, are you you using py.test ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar no other `experiments` packages or modules, but the egg file is repeated three times: `/Users/my_name/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/experiments-0.0.1-py2.7.egg`. Is this a problem?

Comment: @sax `baz.py` is a unittest script

Comment: what package is that? Seems like that egg file may be causing the issue? Is that your own?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes this is my own package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`experiments` is not in `PYTHONPATH`, nor is it *installed* using the standard setuptools technique.  I'm able to replicate your problem, which is resolved by putting `my_repo` in `PYTHONPATH`:

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro-2:my_repo amarshall$ tree .
.
├── experiments
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── baz.py

2 directories, 4 files
Austins-MacBook-Pro-2:my_repo amarshall$ PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/experiments python tests/baz.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/baz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from experiments.foo import FooExperiment
ImportError: No module named experiments.foo
Austins-MacBook-Pro-2:my_repo amarshall$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd` python tests/baz.py
```

Where there's no output, or error in the last line when `PYTHONPATH` is specified, rather than `PATH`

Answer (score -1):

I usually use the following to append path to sys.path:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../myfolder"))
```

With

```
Import sys, os
```

Comment: Manually appending to the path whenever I want to import a class is not a good solution.

Comment: It's not really manually, since those two lines live at the beginning of my file "bad.py". It was the best solution I found to import a module in an "upper" folder (if that make sense)